# Scripting - Powershell, Batch, Robocopy

Tags: powershell, batch-file, scripting

I have to move files from one location to another location with the server.
Files which are older than 30 days are to be moved.
Ex: source path: C:/sharedPath/ Destination Path: D:/BackUpSharepath
The problem here is sharedPath folder contains 'n' of subfolders.
**Files have to be moved without disturbing the folder structure.**
Files moved should be in the same folder structure as of source.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: So what is your specific question?  StackOverFlow is not a free code writing service.  We are here to help you with your existing code. You should be able to do this with `ROBOCOPY`.

Comment: I agree with Squashman, `ROBOCOPY` should get this done for you. Please refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to ask a good question on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Temp2\start\* -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30) } 
foreach($file in $files)
{
$DirectoryName = $file.DirectoryName -replace "start", "finish"
if(!(Test-Path -Path $DirectoryName))
{
    New-Item $DirectoryName -ItemType Directory
}

$newLocation = $file.FullName -replace "start", "finish"
Copy-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $newLocation.ToString() -Force

}
```

Copy-item won't keep structure. So first part I am getting all files with last modified date of 30 days. Then I traverse all files and pull out the directory name and modify it to be the new directory destination(my starting point was folder called start and my destination is finish modify how you need). I then test to see if destination exists. If not I create destination and then copy the file to the new destination.

Comment: My original folder structure was C:\Temp2\start for the starting directory and C:\Temp2\finish for the destination